# I earned the Solstice hat on December 20

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2014

I've been trying to earn more and more hats but now I've experienced a bug.

Today (20th December), I earned the Solstice hat. According to the description [given here](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/), it can be earned by posting or commenting on December 21. But it is not December 21 now.

[image: My hats]

How come I've earned the hat? BTW, UTC time when typing this post is 13:25, So I think this is a bug.

Comment: Happened to me too. Wearing it right now.

Comment: @Palec , Yeah.Just noticed another user having the hat too

Comment: There are always more SO users to complain when things happens too late.  So they time stuff like this to coincide with the earliest UTC time that the date is valid.  Midnight on an island in the Pacific Ocean.  Keeps the guy in Tuvalu happy, it is Sunday 1:40 am there right now.

Comment: Two year old duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159577/135695

Comment: Yeah, its bound to be a time-zone thing. Better to be safe than sorry (yes this is shameless posting for a hat).

Comment: Imagine how dull SE/SO would be if this were the worst problem we faced on the network!

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245122/155739)

Comment: I caught the wrong end of this so am not wearing it

Comment: why doesn't the world revolve around my location?

Comment: Has anyone pointed out that in those places that are currently ahead of UTC, the solstice is actually on December 22?

Comment: @CoolGuy No it doesn't.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign); it is after 12:00 UTC on the 20th, which means it is now the 21st of December **somewhere in the world**. It'll continue to be the 21st somewhere until 13:00 UTC on the 22nd.

See *[Why didn't (or did) I or some other user get a hat although the requirements were (or weren't) fulfilled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer/245123#245123)*:

> ### Leeway on date-based hats
>
> Unless the requirement mentions a specific timezone, hats that are date-based are often awarded for 12 hours before and 13 hours after the specified date in UTC, to accomodate people everywhere in the world. This means you can earn such a hat even though for you it's not even that day yet.

Comment: Aha!  *Somewhere in the world* is key. I was about to ask this same question if I didn't find it in search.  Cheers!

Comment: The actual time zone offsets range from UTC+14 to UTC-11, AFAIK.  Try [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/) and [worldtimezone.com](http://www.worldtimezone.com/).  Maybe +12 .. -13 is close enough.

Comment: Sounds easier and semi-foolproof given the case that the given computer may not know the accurate time zone.

Comment: I admire the intention behind this but it does seem kind of ridiculous. What's the point in giving me a hat for doing something on day X when I didn't do that thing on day X? I get that you cannot feasibly and _reliably_ determine my local time and just use that but ... meh.

Comment: Seems ridiculous to define a day as 48 hours, but OK.

Comment: If they used a strict 24-hour day, they would be stuck dealing with complaints from people for whom the day ended at noon local time. Mild peculiarities are easier to deal with than outright complaints.