# Why didn't I earn the Solstice hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

The description of the Solstice hat is, according to the winter bash site, to "post or comment on 12/21". In my time zone it is the twenty first of December. According to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280816/i-earned-the-solstice-hat-on-december-20) my time zone shouldn't matter. But, I posted [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589902/addition-and-subtraction-with-negative-numbers#comment43604181_27589902) some time ago, as far as I understand I should have earned the solstice hat.
Is there some kind of delay? Are new hats processed in batches (i.e. every hour new hats are awarded)? Is there some condition for the solstice hat  not listed on the winter bash site? Did the gods (Jon Skeet etc.) decide I am unworthy of earning that hat?

Comment: I did get it, but I think it wasn't the 21st in my timezone, so maybe timezone does matter.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think the implicit quality requirement applies to this as well.
Which means it should be upvoted.

From *[Why didn't (or did) I or some other user get a hat although the requirements were (or weren't) fulfilled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer/245123#245123)*:

> Implicit quality requirements
>
> To prevent people from posting nonsense just to earn a hat, most hats
>   that require creating content, especially questions and answers, have
>   some requirements that may not be mentioned in the hat description.
>   Generally this involves questions/answers having a positive score
>   (i.e. getting at least one upvote), not being closed/deleted, etc. If
>   the hat has an additional date requirement, it is okay if the upvote
>   comes in after the time is already over, as long as the content was
>   created during the time.